# Disable parameter depêndency SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a simple report based on a SSAS cube.
I added 3 multivalue parameters : company,projectgroup,businessline
Company is set to empty while the other two have the 'All' option as default.
Behind the scenes SSRS will create a hidden dataset to populate those two parameters.

I have 2 issues :
- Unless I specify the company parameter, my two other parameters are greyed out
- Whenever I change a parameter, it will do a postback and refresh the parameter page.

I think this is due to ssrs automatically creating dependencies between the parameters, but I'm not sure.
The query for the parameter value list of projectgroup and businessline does NOT include a parameter so it should not be dependant to the company parameter.
I also tried disabling the automatic refresh, but this does not make any difference

Is there any way to avoid a postback each time you set/change a parameter of this kind in SSRS?

Following MDX queries were generated by SSRS for my 3 invisble datasets :

Company

WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [Projects].[Company].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [Projects].[Company].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS [Projects].[Company].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL SELECT {[Measures].[ParameterCaption], [Measures].[ParameterValue], [Measures].[ParameterLevel]} ON COLUMNS , [Projects].[Company].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS FROM [Project accounting cube]

ProjGroup

WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [Main Projects].[Project Group].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [Main Projects].[Project Group].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS [Main Projects].[Project Group].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL SELECT {[Measures].[ParameterCaption], [Measures].[ParameterValue], [Measures].[ParameterLevel]} ON COLUMNS , [Main Projects].[Project Group].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS FROM [Project accounting cube]

Business Line

WITH MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterCaption] AS [Main Projects].[Business Line].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_CAPTION MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS [Main Projects].[Business Line].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterLevel] AS [Main Projects].[Business Line].CURRENTMEMBER.LEVEL.ORDINAL SELECT {[Measures].[ParameterCaption], [Measures].[ParameterValue], [Measures].[ParameterLevel]} ON COLUMNS , [Main Projects].[Business Line].ALLMEMBERS ON ROWS FROM [Project accounting cube]

Regards,
Sven Peeters

Comment: In Parameter properties, is it set to to refresh automatically?

Comment: They may not have a parameter, but if the `datasets` are set to the `Company parameter` list, then they are cascading parameters and will refresh each time the `Company parameter` is changed. I'm not totally positive if the refresh automatically setting will stop the refresh.

Comment: I've never seen that refresh option on a parameter make any difference. It really sounds like there is a dependency between the parameters like @WEI_DBA said.  Could you post a screenshot of the projectgroup or businessline dataset query that was generated?  It should be totally possible to have the parameters not doing a postback between selections.

Comment: Hi, The 'refresh automatically' setting doesn't change a thing. I already tried that. I'll post the 3 MDX queries used for company,projgroup and businesline in the article as an update